# Nib prototype uitableviewcell cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

Trying to set and access nib tableview cell. Basically the same as creating uitableview with a prototype tableviewcell and setting its identifier and accessing it through

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Fill table in with data
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
```

Question is how would you do this as a nib. As nib IB doesn't have prototype option?

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

        MPMediaItem *song = [self.songsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString *songTitle = [song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
        NSString *durationLabel = [song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyGenre];
        cell.textLabel.text = songTitle;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = durationLabel;


    return cell;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad {
      [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MusicViewController" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make your cell in the xib file and then in code (probably in viewDidLoad) register the nib with registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:. In cellForRowAtIndexPath, you just dequeue a cell with the same identifier that you passed to the register method. No need to put in the if (cell == nil) clause, because it will never be nil.

Comment: 2013-08-27 22:49:04.888 PaperFold[2225:907] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2380.17/UITableView.m:5471
2013-08-27 22:49:04.902 PaperFold[2225:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'

Comment: @Evilelement, you need to describe what you did that gave that error. Edit your question to show the code you're using now.

Comment: @Evilelement, did you give the cell an identifier of "Cell" in the xib file?

Comment: Yeah, I have. Doubled check, just there.

Comment: basically you are returning an empty cell as you have created custom cell but still using the default properties of cell cell.textLabel.text and cell.detailTextLabel.text
You have to use your custom labels which you have defined in your custom cell

Comment: @Evilelement, try logging cell just above where you return it in cellForRowAtIndexPath to see what it gives.

Comment: @Evilelement, tried what? Did you put in the log? If so what did it give you (or does it not even log because it crashes first)?

Comment: seems like your cell is returning nil. As suggested by @rdelmar try putting NSLog before "return cell" and check out the value of cell

Comment: @rdelmar logging cell, you mean declaring it above cellForRowAtIndexPath? I am still amateur programmer.

Comment: @Evilelement, no, I mean put NSLog(@"%@",cell) just above the line, return cell;

Comment: @rdelmar Its returning (null)

Comment: @Evilelement, that's what I thought you would get, but I have no idea why. You might try breaking you register line into two lines, like UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MusicViewController" bundle:nil]; Then log the nib (NSLog(@"%@",nib), to see what that gives, then the next line would be [self.tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

Comment: @rdelmar Logging back <UINib: 0x1cd8ac00>

Comment: @Evilelement, well, I'm out of ideas -- this should be working. Is there some place you could post the app to, or send it to me so I can look at it?

Comment: @rdelmar https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0n1uVTeL4uNZVF3Q2NqMzk4Y1E/edit?usp=sharing
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0n1uVTeL4uNNE90ck1OcVNWb1k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36367/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-evilelement)

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom tableviewCell with the nib file.After creation you have three files YourCustomCell.h YourCustomCell.m and YourCustomCell.xib

Add the IBOutlet in YourCustomCell.h and connect them in YourCustomCell.xib with respective labels.

Now in cellForRowAtIndexPath: add the following:

```
    YourCustomCell *yourCustomCell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    yourCustomCell.labelInCustomCell.textLabel.text = songTitle;
    yourCustomCell.detailsLabelInCustomCell.textLabel.text = durationLabel;

    return yourCustomCell;
```

Hope this help you.